# Return value in multiples of 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having some difficulties with my code namely to do with multiples.

Firstly, if `basket.length` is greater or equal to 4 (4, 8, 12, 16...) then I would like the following element to be displayed:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="basket.length % 4 === 0">
  You need to select at least {{ getNumberOfMuffins() }} muffins 
</div>
```

Secondly, if the value of `this.basket.length` is not or greater of equal to 4 (4, 8, 12, 16...), then round it up to the next multiple of 4. If it is a multiple of 4 then just return the number. For example:

if `this.basket.length === 3`, then go up to 4
if `this.basket.length === 5`, then go up to 8
if `this.basket.length === 9`, then go up to 12

```
getNumberOfMuffins() {
  // do some stuff
  // return the rounded number of muffins required
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide by 4, call `Math.ceil`, then multiply by 4:

```js
const getNumberOfMuffins = basketLength => 4 * Math.ceil(basketLength / 4);

console.log(getNumberOfMuffins(4));
console.log(getNumberOfMuffins(5));
console.log(getNumberOfMuffins(6));
```

Answer (score 1):

Naiv and self-explaining approach (...3->4, 4->**8**, 5->8...):

```
getNumberOfMuffins() {
  return this.basket.length + (4 - this.basket.length % 4);
}
```

Naiv and self-explaining approach (...3->4, 4->**4**, 5->8...):

```
getNumberOfMuffins() {
  if (this.basket.length % 4 === 0) return this.basket.length;
  return this.basket.length + (4 - this.basket.length % 4);
}
```

Different and short using rounding (...3->4, 4->**4**, 5->8...):

```
getNumberOfMuffins() {
  // divide by 4, floor to hole number (|0), add one and "multiply back" with 4
  return ((this.basket.length/4|0)+1)*4;
}
```